# file path from the url disappears on redirect

Tags: php, url, moodle

I am still very new to `Moodle`. I have tried to set up `Moodle` since this week but it is not working well. I have installed all the underlying server `apache` and `mysql`. I have also enabled the required extensions in the php.ini file:

```
php_curl.dll,
php_fileinfo.dll,
php_gd2.dll,
php_intl.dll,
php_mbstring.dll, 
php_mysqli.dll, 
php_openssl.dll, 
php_soap.dll, 
php_xmlrpc.dll.
```

However, whenever I want to navigate to another page or clicking the log-in button, I get this page here where the `php` extension is dropped all the time. So, what you can see is not the moodle site, but just a hierarchy of files. I always have to manually augment the url by the php part, but this is not a solution.

I hope you can help me out. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: It has been ages since I've seen a Moodle install, but it looks like it's probably built with URL rewriting in mind, which you might not have enabled (or there is no correct .htaccess file). If this isn't the problem, did you reach the initial install page?

Comment: @Ynhockey: Firstly, thank you for your reply. I have reached the initial install page, but with just the aid of adding the "index.php" initally to the url. I am still running the Moodle-website on my localhost. On the internet people say that you need to enable the extension "php_fileinfo.dll". I did it, but it is still the same.

Comment: If you need to manually insert `index.php`, it means you haven't configured a start page. You can do so by using `DirectoryIndex`, for example: `DirectoryIndex index.php`. However, from your reply it looks like you just installed everything manually. Have you considered using a package that comes with the most common configs? In CentOS just installing the packages is good enough, but on Windows you might want to use something like XAMPP.

Comment: @Ynhockey: I am running the Moodle-Website on Windows and I use the Apache server and have linked it with PHP and MySQl. Is XAMPP better than Apache? I am following a tutorial right now on Udemy, however the technologies seem to be outdated which were used in the video and the discussion forum is also not active anymore.

Comment: XAMPP is just an automatic installer for Apache, PHP, MySQL and more. It does much of the basic work for you, and covers many of the pitfalls, likely one of which you are experiencing.

Comment: @Ynhockey: I am very new to this field. So if I set up Moodle via XAMPP, do I need to uninstall the previously installed Apache Server and MySql, so that the ports won't be occupied by those applications? I have installed XAMPP tried to run it, but it cannot run because of Apache24 I guess. That is just my guessing.